# Change values of pixels of a GeoTIFF in Python with conditions

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, array

I would like to change the values of pixels based on some conditions. I am using `rasterio` and `python` to modify the values.

This is what I am doing

```
import nunpy as np
import raterio
def changeLabel(arr):
    arr[np.where( arr == 103 )] = 10        # class 1
    arr[np.where( arr == 33 )]  = 20        # class 2
    arr[np.where( arr == 65 )]  = 30        # class 3
    arr[np.where( arr == 1 )]   = 40        # class 4
    arr[np.where( arr == 9 )]   = 50        # class 5
    arr[np.where( arr == 17 )]  = 60        # class 6
    arr[np.where( arr == 129 )] =  0        # water / no data
    arr[np.where( arr == 0 )]   =  1        # background
    return arr
## read my file
src = rasterio.open('Myfile.tif')
image_data = src.read(1)
image_data = changeLabel(image_data)
```

This process works but it takes a very long time for large images. I would like to use `gdal_calc.py` but I am not sure if this will be the same. This is what I tried but it does not work

```
gdal_calc.py -A 'myFile.tif' --outfile='outFile.tif' --calc="10*(A==103)+\
20*(A==33)+30*(A==65)+40*(A==1)+50*(A==9)+60*(A==17)+1*(A==0)" --NoDataValue=129
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
call gdal_calc ^
--calc "((A==103)*10) + ((A==33)*20) + ((A==65)*30) + ((A==1)*40) + ((A==9)*50) + ((A==17)*60) + ((A==129)*0) + ((A==0)*1)" ^
--outfile "output.tif" ^
--overwrite ^
--format GTiff ^
--NoDataValue 0 ^
--co COMPRESS=DEFLATE ^
--co "TILED=YES" ^
-A "input.tif" ^
--A_band 1
```

You may have to experiment with the [hideNoData](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-hideNoData) and [NoDataValue](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-NoDataValue) options depending on if and how nodata is defined in the input raster.